# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'btusb': Operation not permitted

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, bluetooth

I have recently started using a new Ubuntu desktop and it does not come with a Bluetooth adapter. I am using the UB500 from tp-link. After plugging it in I could not see any devices to connect to so I followed [Bluetooth scan doesn't detect any device on Ubuntu 21.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370663/bluetooth-scan-doesnt-detect-any-device-on-ubuntu-21-10). Everything was running fine until suddenly yesterday I unplugged the adapter while the computer was running and from then I am unable to use the adapter.

I tried following the document again but this time it's throwing an error when

```
~$ modprobe btusb
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'btusb': Operation not permitted
```

```
~$ lsmod | grep -i bt and: sudo dmesg | grep bt
grep: and:: No such file or directory
grep: sudo: No such file or directory
grep: dmesg: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The is because of SecureBoot, disable it in the BIOS settings.

Comment: Try sudo modprobe btusb.

Comment: `sudo modprobe btusb 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'btusb': Invalid argument`. This is my work desktop, I don't think I am permitted to do that.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lsmod | grep -i bt` and: `sudo dmesg | grep bt` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I've updated the results. Can you please take a look at it? Thanks for the welcome

Comment: These are two seperate commands; not one command with the word 'and'. Please try again.

Comment: I was trying to install Tp-link UB500 using [this link][1]. I am facing the same issue:

    # sudo modprobe -v btusb

    insmod /lib/modules/5.15.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko 
    modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'btusb': Invalid argument

I have run those commands

    # lsmod | grep -i bt

    btrtl                  24576  0
    btbcm                  24576  0
    btintel                40960  0
    bluetooth             704512  10 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep



  [1]: https://github.com/tedboudros/tplink-ub500-linux-patch-guide

Comment: # sudo dmesg | grep bt

    [    2.253949] btusb: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
    [    2.278328] btusb: disagrees about version of symbol btbcm_setup_patchram
    [    2.278331] btusb: Unknown symbol btbcm_setup_patchram (err -22)

Comment: while making btusb.ko some message appeared
CC [M]  /home/user/linux-5.15/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/user/linux-5.15/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
  BTF [M] /home/user/linux-5.15/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
Skipping BTF generation for /home/user/linux-5.15/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux

Comment: @ViratRaaz Please start your own new question.

Comment: @chili555 Pipewire solved my problem. Thank you for your kind support.