# Ubuntu22.04 Bluetooth connectivity issue

Tags: networking, 20.04, sound, bluetooth, 22.04

I have an old laptop **HP pavilion g4** and have dual boot setup on it. The laptop has **INTERNAL bluetooth + wifi combo adapter** Qualcomm Atheros AR9485.
Everything used to work fine in windows until a few months (around 2021) when a windows update came and the bluetooth stopped connecting in windows.

In case of ubuntu, bluetooth will **only connect once** when computer is **booted initially**,

Once connected,

> - If some form of audio is playing, **when the connection is established initially,** then it'll stay connected for **the duration of which the audio stream is playing**,
> - While the audio is playing, it plays in **slow volume** (even at max out volume, it plays at around 30%)
> - once the **audio stream to the bluetooth device stops**, then in and around 5-6 seconds, **the device disconnects,** and **stays that way**
> - **bluetooth settings menu becomes unresposive.** and the toggle switch for bluetooth stop responding.

So, recently I bought an external bluetooth adapter [TP-link ub500](https://www.tp-link.com/in/home-networking/adapter/ub500/) and installed it in windows and it works fine there but, in case of Ubuntu, it had the same connectivity issues listed previously. So I followed several links and tried different solutions.

In **Ubuntu 20.04** firstly,

> - I tried [the top answer of this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370663/bluetooth-scan-doesnt-detect-any-device-on-ubuntu-21-10) which didn't work,
> - then i found out that support for [ub500 was added in Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg94501.html) so I updated my pc to that version.

Now, in **Ubuntu 22.04** the same problem persists
**Everything listed above except the low volume issue** which was resolved.

Then I checked `lsusb` to see if it was displaying the adapter, **which it was**

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 029: ID 0cf3:311d Qualcomm Atheros Communications Bluetooth
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0348 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP Truevision HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2357:0604 TP-Link TP!Link UB500 Adapter
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Then ,I thought that pc was using the internal adapter instead of the external one

> - [so I tried this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898881/deactivate-internal-bluetooth-adapter-while-leaving-usb-dongle-online) solution, but then too the **issue was present**.
> - So I used `bluetoothctl` to [check which device it was using](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331009/bluetooth-on-ubuntu-20-04-constantly-disconnecting) and found that **it was using the external adapter** which I confirmed by comparing the MAC address of both the internal and external device.
> - Installed and updated bluez.

In the end, after all that, **the problem still persists** and I am not sure how should I approach this now.