# modprobe btusb error

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, modprobe

I am using a Ubuntu desktop 20.04.4 LTS with linux kernel 5.15.0-41-generic. I bought UB500 from tp-link. After plugging it doesnt turn on-off.

I tried every steps exactly and following the answer from [document](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370663/bluetooth-scan-doesnt-detect-any-device-on-ubuntu-21-10) but it's throwing an error when

```
~$ modprobe btusb
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'btusb': Invalid argument

~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1038:1838 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries Aerox 3 Wireless
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1038:1260 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries Arctis 7
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 040b:0a67 Weltrend Semiconductor Weltrend USB Mouse
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:0604 TP-Link TP-Link UB500 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What exactly steps you did? The accepted answer is wrong for your system if you literally ran all those commands.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` command.

Comment: And if you want to load a module you need to make it with sudo.

Comment: @nobody The device mentioned has been added to the 5.15 kernel already and doesn't require tinkering with `btusb`. So it is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Pilot6 I applied the accepted answer, couldn't turn it on or off before I did. But the system saw the device before.

Comment: You applied a wrong answer and broke btusb.

Comment: How can I fix this

Comment: I will add  it to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have exactly the same device (TP-Link could sell another device with the same name), then you don't need to do anything to get it working.

You can see it [here](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/jammy/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=9b77a8dc1c95e9c4e0f07afdcc2777952d5f0b46)

So you built a wrong kernel module and replaced the correct one. You can't start it because it doesn't match the kernel version.

You can fix it this way:

1. Boot with a previous kernel using grub.
2. Reinstall the `5.15.0-41-generic` linux image and modules using Synaptic.
3. Reboot again.

Comment: It's UB500, It is written on the back of the device.

Comment: thanks, its worked.