TP Link UB500 fails to work as expected
I recently bought a Bluetooth dongle TP Link UB500 and tried to use it on my Ubuntu 22.04.5 machine and it connects but failed to pair and there is not any successful attempt to use it as expected like casting audio to my Bluetooth Speaker or even doing any activity on my Bluetooth Keyboard like pressing keys...
lsusb:
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2357:0604 TP-Link TP-Link Bluetooth USB Adapter
<some devices like mouse and keyboard...>
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

dmesg | egrep -i "blue|firm":
[32363.755083] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -16
[32363.760951] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -16
[32363.763987] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -16
[32363.768976] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -16
[32370.087975] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -16

lsmod | grep "bt":
btusb                  77824  0
btrtl                  32768  1 btusb
btintel                57344  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
btmtk                  12288  1 btusb
bluetooth            1028096  44 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
btcoexist             294912  1 rtl8192ee
rtlwifi               143360  3 rtl_pci,btcoexist,rtl8192ee

journalctl -f -u bluetooth:
Nov 27 00:17:19 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for <DEVICE ADDRESS>

journalctl -xeu bluetooth | grep blue | grep -v systemd:
Nov 24 04:17:20 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[7993]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
░░ Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully.
Nov 24 04:17:20 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[7993]: Starting SDP server
Nov 24 04:17:21 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[7993]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
░░ Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has begun execution
░░ A start job for unit bluetooth.service has begun execution.
Nov 25 14:44:39 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
░░ Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully.
Nov 25 14:44:39 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Starting SDP server
Nov 25 14:44:39 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Nov 25 16:18:16 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Nov 25 16:18:16 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.203 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/1
Nov 25 16:18:16 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.203 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/2
Nov 25 16:18:16 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.203 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Nov 25 16:18:16 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.203 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
Nov 25 16:18:48 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for F7:7E:CB:74:F6:A9
Nov 25 16:20:16 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Wrong size of start discovery return parameters
Nov 25 16:24:43 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for F7:7E:CB:74:F6:A9
Nov 25 16:27:26 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Nov 25 16:51:03 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for F7:7E:CB:74:F6:A9
Nov 25 16:51:36 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Wrong size of start discovery return parameters
Nov 25 17:10:41 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Wrong size of start discovery return parameters
Nov 26 00:08:56 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Nov 26 01:18:53 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.203 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/1
Nov 26 01:18:53 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.203 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/2
Nov 26 01:18:53 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.203 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Nov 26 01:18:53 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.203 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit bluetooth.service has begun execution
░░ A stop job for unit bluetooth.service has begun execution.
Nov 26 01:18:57 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Terminating
Nov 26 01:19:02 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Stopping SDP server
Nov 26 01:19:02 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[17984]: Exit
░░ The unit bluetooth.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit bluetooth.service has finished
░░ A stop job for unit bluetooth.service has finished.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has begun execution
░░ A start job for unit bluetooth.service has begun execution.
Nov 26 15:18:18 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
░░ Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully.
Nov 26 15:18:35 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Starting SDP server
Nov 26 15:18:36 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Nov 26 15:18:40 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Nov 26 15:18:40 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/1
Nov 26 15:18:40 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/2
Nov 26 15:18:40 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Nov 26 15:18:40 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:07:42 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/3
Nov 26 23:16:11 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Wrong size of start discovery return parameters
Nov 26 23:16:14 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:16:14 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:16:14 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:16:14 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:16:14 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/3
Nov 26 23:17:38 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci1/A2DP/LDAC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:17:38 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Nov 26 23:17:38 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci1/A2DP/LDAC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:17:38 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci1/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:17:38 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci1/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:18:17 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for F7:7E:CB:74:F6:A9
Nov 26 23:40:16 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci1/A2DP/LDAC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:40:16 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci1/A2DP/LDAC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:40:16 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci1/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:40:16 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci1/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:40:31 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:40:31 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:40:31 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:40:31 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:40:47 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:40:47 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:40:47 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:40:47 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:40:58 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:40:58 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: src/adv_monitor.c:btd_adv_monitor_power_down() Unexpected NULL btd_adv_monitor_manager object upon power down
Nov 26 23:40:58 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:40:58 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Nov 26 23:40:58 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
Nov 26 23:41:18 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.14 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/3
Nov 27 00:17:19 BrownTurbo-Linux bluetoothd[1924]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for <ADDRESS>

hcitool scan:
Device is not available: No such device

hcitool lescan:
Could not open device: No such device

uname -a:
Linux BrownTurbo-Linux 6.8.0-49-generic #49~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov  6 17:42:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


This problem, I think, was seen in 21.04 and we have moved on quite a bit  over three years) since then. However, you could try the instructions in the following link. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370663/bluetooth-scan-doesnt-detect-any-device-on-ubuntu-21-10/1371453#1371453 (My hopes are not high.)
